# IIS-Express error in Visual Studio - cannot run the projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

In Visual Studio when I run any web application, it is not launching. I cannot see the IIS express icon in tray and when I checked the logs in event view it says

```
The worker process failed to initialize correctly
```

and therefore could not be started. I even tried to run IIS express through cmd, not working. it gives

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe  /trace:error
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 8009921
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 8009937
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 8009937
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 8009937
Start listenerChannel http:0
Error (rc=80070433) in UlInitialize. Exiting
Error initializing ULATQ.  hr = 80070433
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Process Model Shutdown called
Unable to start iisexpress.

The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion.
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, what is wrong with IIS express on my machine ,any help ?

Comment: I think it's a permission issue. Please check https://forums.iis.net/t/1192376.aspx

Comment: updated the detailed error.

Comment: Please edit the question and share the content of `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config`.

Comment: it is too big to be pasted, any specific section you want to see ?

Comment: Look for applicationhost.config file at `<solution-name>\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` location, try removing this file and run solution again.

Comment: you specifically meant to delete applicationhost.config in that hidden folder? , because I already tried deleting the entire .vs folder !

Comment: Maybe you can try to uninstall the current version of iis express and install the new version.